# UIButton in UIView in UIScrollView not loading properly

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

Kinda confusing title but oh well.

I have a UIScrollView in my viewController, in that is 3 UIViews with some buttons in each. I download data from a server and populate it into the view and this works as soon as you start scrolling the UIScrollView, but sometimes the buttons only partially load.

Usually its the button label without my formatting added to it. The button works and as soon as you click the button the rest of view loads correctly. Basically if the UIScrollView is touched in anyway it displays correctly.

I've tried adding and removing the scrollView to the view and I've called [scrollView setNeedsDisplay] and the exact same thing happens.

Anyone come across this?

EDIT: screen shot before and after (just basic to demonstrate whats happening)

[image] [image]

Comment: "but sometimes the buttons only partially load". Could you please upload a screenshot ?

Comment: Dodgy screenshot taken, the available is just a place holder for something later but the same problem is happening with peoples names and stuff.

Comment: I hope you're not adding the buttons in a background thread...

Comment: Nope, There is no threading in the class dealing with the UI. Download of data is on a separate thread though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was building the buttons in drawRect which was causing issues. Built the buttons in a separate method and it worked fine.